# subnumeric search on integer array

Tags: php, arrays, numbers

I have an array with numbers in php, for example

```
$data=array(1500,1515,1300,1466,15,151)
```

I want to find the numbers that contains 15 in that array, in this example it would be

```
$result=array(1500,1515,15,151).
```

I know that I can convert them to string and search with strpos but I would like a faster method using integers division/mult.

Any tip?

UPDATE AFTER ACCEPTED ANSWER.

Using this code, I have tested both method, string and integer, 10000 searchs in numbers with 1 to 6 digits. The faster method is the string method.

```
<?php
    $data = array();
    for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++)
        $data[]=rand(0,100000);

    $start1 = microtime(true);
    for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
        foreach($data as $j=>$v)
        {
            $needle = false;
            while($v && !$needle) {
                if($v%100 == 15) // Check if last two digits are 15.
                    $needle = true;
                $v = floor($v/10); // Remove last digit.
            }
        }
    $end1 = microtime(true);

    $start2 = microtime(true);
    for($i=0;$i<100;$i++)
        foreach($data as $j=>$v)
            $needle=strpos($v, '15') !== false;
    $end2 = microtime(true);

    echo "int: ".($end1-$start1)."<br>string: ".($end2-$start2);
?>
```

The output was:

```
int: 1.2258439064026
string: 0.4002320766449
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  Is there any reason why you think using numerics would be faster?

Comment: I have my doubts, thats why i'm asking,  i have a lot of numbers in the array, and I'm trying to optimize the  speed

Comment: given the fact that you'd have to iteratively divide by 10 and take modulo 100 to find `15` I think strpos would almost certainly be faster.

Comment: This seems such an odd task to be doing. What on earth could it be useful for? Or is it just a coding challenge?

Comment: Integers are a lot faster than arrays or strings in theory, and my array is huge, I'm just checking if there is a method, if not, I will use strpos. Probably convert to string is faster, but i'm just curious about the possible solutions

Comment: I have updated the question with the calcs with the accepted response. First, thanks to Progrock.

Comment: So strings were more than 3x faster. Always nice to have your intuition confirmed. Interesting (and useful) to see the results, thanks for posting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping to math functions, without strings:

```
<?php
$data = array(1500,1515,1300,1466,15,151);

$filtered = array_filter($data,
    function($i)
    {
        $needle = false;
        while($i && !$needle) {
            if($i%100 == 15) // Check if last two digits are 15.
                $needle = true;
            $i = floor($i/10); // Remove last digit.
        }

        return $needle;
    }
);

var_dump($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1500)
  [1]=>
  int(1515)
  [4]=>
  int(15)
  [5]=>
  int(151)
}
```

This was inspired by Nick's comment.  The 15 check takes a number, checks if it ends with 15, if not removes a digit, and so on.

Comment: This solution seems cool, it is specifically done for 15 or 2 digits (the %100 operation) but can be easily changed to genetic. I will accept this one as solution and i will make a test with some numbers to see if it is the faster method.

Comment: @hamboy75 yes do get back with results comparing each.  You might want to loop and filter as you go instead of using array_filter.

Answer (score 1):

Php will coerce to string as you go:

```
<?php

$data = array(1500,1515,1300,1466,15,151);

$filtered = array_filter($data, function($n) {
    return strpos($n, '15') !== false;
});

var_dump($filtered);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  int(1500)
  [1]=>
  int(1515)
  [4]=>
  int(15)
  [5]=>
  int(151)
}
```

But if loading your array into memory is the issue, I'd consider chunking the task.

Comment: I think OP was aware of this option but was looking for mathematics way (I also believe using `strpos` is better way to do that...)

Comment: I only mention it, as it sounds as if the OP perhaps was considering doing something like: `array_map('strval', $data)` first.

Comment: array_filter with anon function, or loop and filter for performance?

Comment: I DO think your way is better (upvoted) - but sadly not what OP was looking for